# An integer I pass as an argument becomes a method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a function. Here is the code.

```
def get_sum(a,b)
  if a == b do
    return a
    end
  else
    total = 0
    for num in a...b
      total += num
    end
    return total
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `b' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this?

Comment: `if a == b do`, remove do. It should be  `if a == b`

Comment: Remove the `end` before the `else`, as well as the `do`!

Comment: How are you calling your method?

Comment: and to add to @pjs comment remove the return keywords too. (Ruby always returns the last statement so these are not needed)

Comment: Don't use `for num in a...b`. `num` will be leaked (left around to consume space). Instead use `each` or `times` with a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `do` for `if`s

```
if a == b
  return a
end
```

Note that you can do the same thing so

```
def get_sum(a, b)
  return a if a == b
  (a...b).inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: `(a...b).inject(:+)` returns the same than `(a...b).inject(0) { |total, item| total += item }`

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved it, I knew it was something simple. Haven't seen the inject method before any ideas why it is returning nil when I pass negative numbers to the get_sum method

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Removing `do` only reveals another problem with the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have a block `do` ... `end` after `b`. Neither the keyword `if` nor the syntax sugar form `... == ...` accepts a block. The only possibility left to interpret your code syntactically is to interpret `b` as a method that takes this `do` ... `end` block, and that is how it is parsed.